# Why is the domain different on the inverse of this function?

Tags: inverse

I have the function

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 - 1}$$

The domain of this function is $(-1,1)$ and the range is $\mathbb{R}$.

When I find the inverse of this, this becomes

$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1 + \sqrt{4x^2+1}}{2x}$$

The domain seems to be different, now that I cannot have zero in the denominator. This should match up with the range of the initial function. Why does this happen?

Comment: $f^{-1}(0)=0$ exists and is well defined. Review your derivation of $f^{-1}$ and recheck the conditions at each step.

Comment: In general, the domain of the inverse function will be exactly the range of the original function. Note that the range is all values the function *will actually output*, as opposed to the codomain, which is simply the *space into which the function outputs*. (You may not have heard the term codomain yet, in which case it's nothing to worry about for now). I do not believe you have the correct expression for $f^{-1}$ (and unfortunately I suspect I cannot give you a correct expression since I doubt that there is a nice closed-form representation for it).

Comment: @dxiv I did, I confirmed that even on wolframalpha the inverse I have is correct

Comment: @Trumpetplayer0098 Your formula doesn't work for $x=0$ so it's not *correct*. See the David's answer why.

Comment: You have the correct inverse for the domain$(-\infty,1)\cup (1, \infty)$ but it is not correct for $(-1,1)$  What do you think you should change inside that interval?  Now at $x=0$, you are still undefined.  But the limit exists.  And since you know $f(0) = 0$, you can define it for that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to think of it: write your function as $y$ in terms of $x$, your aim is to find $x$ in terms of $y$.  We have
$$y=\frac{x}{x^2-1}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad yx^2-x-y=0\ .$$
If $y=0$ obviously $x=0$, if $y\ne0$ we can use the quadratic formula to get
$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}\ .$$
There must be only one value of $x$ so we need to decide whether to take the $+$ sign or the $-$ sign.  One way to do this is to note that $x$ will be a continuous function of $y$ (draw the graph of $y$ in terms of $x$ to see this), and
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}\to\infty\quad\hbox{as}\quad y\to0\ ,$$
so we must reject the $+$ sign (note that you got this wrong).

So the inverse function is
$$f^{-1}(y)=\cases{0&if $y=0$\cr \frac{1-\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}&if $y\ne0$,\cr}$$
or if you prefer
$$f^{-1}(x)=\cases{0&if $x=0$\cr \frac{1-\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}&if $x\ne0$.\cr}$$

---

Alternatively we can rationalise the numerator to get
$$f^{-1}(y)=-\frac{2y}{1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}}$$
which is valid both for $y\ne0$ and for $y=0$.

Comment: That makes sense, I was moreorless expecting it to have single function that would have the exact range. I guess you kind of have to be aware that switching the Xs and Ys won't provide the entire answer, tricky question

Comment: You can get a single formula, see the bit I just added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to express $f^{-1}$ in a nice form, using the standard trick of replacing $f(x)$ by $y$ and then switch the $y$'s and $x$'s, I obtain:

$x=y/(y^2-1)$

Now my goal is isolate $y$ so that I can write $y=$'stuff' where $y$ is now $f^{-1}(x)$.

In an effort to isolate, $y$, I multiply, both sides by $y^2-1$ to obtain:

$x(y^2-1)=y$

Next I distribute the $x$ and then subtract $y$ from both sides, yielding:

$xy^2-x-y=0$
Now I reorder terms, and factor out a common $y$

$y(xy-1)-x=0$

And now I believe the problem is becoming evident: There is no easy way to isolate the $y$'s from the $x$'s so that I can get the $x$'s to the other side and complete my attempt to solve for $y$.

Comment: I believe @Trumpetplayer0098 used the quadratic formula on $$xy^{2} - y - x = 0$$ with $a = x, b = 1, c = -x$

Comment: @Shai +1 except that for $x=0$ that's not a quadratic.

Comment: Ah, and that would explain some of the issues with the resulting expression, as you actually get *two* (and a third at $x=0$) formulas, each one will be valid for part of the original function's graph.